# What Do Mathematicians Do?

Tags: soft-question, big-list, philosophy

The American Mathematical Society maintains a web page entitled "[What Do Mathematicians Do?](http://www.ams.org/profession/career-info/math-work/math-work)" which references two interesting surveys. (One of the reference links is broken, but this one works: [What Do Mathematicians Do?](http://ime.math.arizona.edu/g-teams/Profiles/MT/berrick.pdf) by A.J. Berrick.) Both surveys have - notwithstanding their merits - a somehow narrow view on what working mathematicians actually do: somehow too general and somehow too specific. And I am not really happy with both of them.

What I am looking for is an (as comprehensive as possible) list of catchy descriptions of what working mathematicians *actually* do (i) in laymen's terms, (ii) in working mathematician's terms, and (iii) in philosopher's of mathematics terms.

The laymen's list would include:

- **propose** (definitions)
- **conjecture** (theorems)
- **prove** (theorems)
- **understand** (proofs)
- **classify** (objects)
- **characterize** (objects)
- **calculate** (objects)
- **count** (objects)
- **"visualize"** (objects = structures)
- **represent** (abstract objects by concrete objects)
- **construct** (new objects out of given objects)

> **Question 1:** How should/could this list be extended? And how could it be organized, with regard to the fact that - for example - to
>   *propose* a definition and to *conjecture* a theorem is somehow related, and that to *count* (i.e. to give the cardinality of some set
>   of objects) is to *prove* a theorem?

Concerning the (idealized) working mathematician's list, I am insecure how she would describe her daily work in abstract terms.

> **Question 2:** Some examples how working mathematicians would describe their work in abstract terms other than those above and below?

Concerning the philosopher's (of mathematics) list, it might contain items like

- find **natural isomorphisms**
- find **pairs of adjoint functors**

> **Question 3:** How should/could *this* list be extended? Especially without the categorical bias?

Comment: In laymen's term, a mathematician sits in front of a monitor and presses keys on a keyboard. Slightly more detailed, he probably reads and understands many papers, both mathematical papers and papers from the discipline he's currently working on. Then maybe he's explaining what he learned from these papers to other people, and how relevant it is or could be for what they are doing. Independent of whether what I wrote above is true, I hope it gives some idea what "laymen's terms" could mean.

Comment: You are right, Thomas, there are many kinds of laymen. I am thinking of the *interested layman*.

Comment: Collect grant money.

Comment: I beg your pardon, Potato?

Comment: @HansStricker It's what academic mathematicians do, in layman's terms.

Comment: Ok, that's funny. You should have written **collect** (grant money) +1

Comment: **Tame** (undergraduates)

Comment: **solve** and **produce** (problems)

Comment: Joking aside, I don't think this is a particularly productive line of inquiry. If you asked an academic mathematician what they do, you would probably get an answer along the lines of "prove theorems, solve problems, and teach." All of the items you list are just aspects of those things. I think you would get more milage by asking a more specific question, like "What does it really mean to prove a theorem?"

Comment: Goedel's incompleteness theorem loosely interpreted says that mathematics always will require innovation. This has been my experience and probably that of most mathematicians. Most good theorems have some accidental aspect to them.

Comment: I like the following quote to describe what mathematicians do 'in laymen's terms':

"Oh, he seems like an okay person, except for being a little strange in some ways. All day he sits at his desk and scribbles, scribbles, scribbles. Then, at the end of the day, he takes the sheets of paper he's scribbled on, scrunches them all up, and throws them in the trash can." --J. von Neumann's housekeeper, describing her employer

Comment: **Disregard** people saying things like "You are good at this stuff, how much is $234\times 683$?"

Comment: Mathematicians make connections

Comment: I think that Ruben Hersh's book [Experiencing Mathematics: What Do We Do When We Do Mathematics?](https://www.google.co.in/search?rlz=1C1GIWA_enIN601IN601&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=628&q=Experiencing+Mathematics&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLUz9U3SDFOy7VU4tFP1zfMykk3rayoSNYScCwtycgvCsl3ys_P9s_LqQQAysGvoS0AAAA&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbw5PBz_nNAhUIsI8KHZuKBJUQxA0IUDAH) should be a very relevant read for your question.

Comment: Also see [this paper](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi3-PKs0PnNAhULMY8KHThlCH4QFgglMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fabs%2Fmath%2F0702396&usg=AFQjCNFTV_txYEXnWFQ-uMSQ81bSn5ndYA&bvm=bv.127178174,d.c2I) by Terence Tao.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a philosophical answer and I don't know if this is what you were looking for, but in general what a mathematician does is finding an abstract representation of reality (or some reality).
This is why mathematics finds so many applications in physics, for example.

Through symbolic manipulation, mathematics creates representations that, respecting some fixed rules (axioms), define the world and make predictions about its laws.

Please, note that "reality" and "the world" do not necessarily imply our reality and our world. I can conjecture a reality in infinite dimensions for example. However, even if that reality does not exist, I can still create its representation, and it will hold true should that world actually exist. Minkowsky created a metric used by Einstein way before it was needed, for example.

So, mathematics abstracts concepts creating symbols that can be manipulated, and by so doing we can derive rules and make predictions.

Everything else is a redefinition of these concepts, or an application.

As another mathematician, whose name I forget, said regarding mathematical physics: "To summarize, the end of mathematical physics is not merely to facilitate the numerical calculation of certain constants or the integration of certain differential equations. It is more, it is above all to disclose to the physicist the concealed harmonies of things by furnishing him with a new point of view".

This holds for other sciences besides physics, of course.

Comment: @goblin that is the same of what I wrote, it holds for other sciences besides physics (of course).